# Configuring UseIdentityColumn in EF Core 2.0

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I am porting an application written in .NET Core 3.0 to .NET Core 2.0. 
Below is the code that works with .NET Core 3.0

```
public class ArtistConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Artist>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Artist> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasKey(a => a.Id);

        builder
            .Property(m => m.Id)
            .UseIdentityColumn();

        builder
            .Property(m => m.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        builder
            .ToTable("Artists");
    }
}
```

I am getting an error at UseIdentityColumn -

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'PropertyBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseIdentityColumn' and no accessible extension method 'UseIdentityColumn' accepting a first argument of type 'PropertyBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  MyMusic.Data

Is there a different configuration to achieve this for .NET Core 2.0?

some answers suggest using UseSqlServerIdentityColumn, however, this does not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in a version change with "deprecation" vortex!

If you only want version 2.x, then you don't need to conditionals.  BUT I'm going to leave the conditionals to show what is going on.

Note, your package imports ("PackageReference"'s below) have to alter their versions as well. <-- I think this is probably what you are missing.

the csproj file (below)

You'll have to adjust to 2.0 and 3.0.  But you get the idea with 2.1 and 3.1.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.1;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

<!--  [2.1.1,2.2.0) means .. very explicit that it should be "Anything >= to 2.1.1" but also "less then 2.2.0" .... because DotNetCore 2.2 is not in LTS (long term support) -->
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp2.1'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="[2.1.1,2.2.0)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="[2.1.1,2.2.0)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="[2.1.1,2.2.0)" />
  </ItemGroup>

<!-- 3.1.* is simplified version of anything 3.1.x of course -->
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp3.1'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.1.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.*" />
  </ItemGroup>



  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp2.1'">
    <DefineConstants>NETCORE;NETCORE2_1</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp3.1'">
    <DefineConstants>NETCORE;NETCORE3_1</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>


</Project>
```

and now in your .cs code

```
#if (NETCOREAPP2_1)
            builder.Property(c => c.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
#endif

#if (NETCOREAPP3_1)
            builder.Property(c => c.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().UseIdentityColumn();
#endif
```

Side topic.

the 3.1.* is called "floating version"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#floating-versions

---

The other method ..  [2.1.1,2.2.0)  .. I think it is called "Semantic Versioning" .. can been seen at the below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#version-ranges

.........

LTS (long term support)

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

2.2 is "out"

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-2-2-will-reach-end-of-life-on-december-23-2019/

Comment: thank you for showing me conditionals, learnt something new :)

Comment: @Kush.  I added some more packagereference super-magic to this answer.